# what's the different open Picture file python2 open.read and python3 open.read

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am a Chinese programmer with poor English. I have a problem.

I'm a novice. How can I get the output in Python 2 in Python 3 environment? I want to know the difference between their opening binary files. I hope to get a reply. Thank you.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't think there's much difference. But printing a binary file doesn't generally make sense.

Comment: Please do not add code in form of screenshots!

Answer (score 0):

Following is happening here:

Python 2 doesn't have a type to represent raw bytes. Instead, these bytes are represented by a string, and when printing, it tries to output the bytes as characters. If a character isn't ASCII though, it results in weird characters with question-mark icons etc.

In Python 3, a bytes type was introduced. Opening a file as binary in Python 3 will return a bytes type. When printing the bytes type, all bytes that can't be represented by ASCII properly are escaped as something between `\x00` and `\xFF` (hexadecimal).

So the difference is that Python 3 has the capability to store and print raw bytes, while Python 2 doesn't.